# Cassandra frequent write timeout exception

Tags: java, cassandra, centos, timeout, batch-processing

I have `Apache Cassandra 3.11.4` on `CentOS 7.5` and I have a `Java` application to read from `db2` and insert into `Cassandra`.

I use a batch statement for inserting into `Cassandra`, but over time write latency increases and I encounter the write timeout exception.

I have increased the value of `write_request_timeout_in_ms` but it does not help and it only postpones the write timeout exception.

Comment: Did you consider reading the information related to each of the tags you've attached to your question? The [tag:batch-file] tag, is for `MS-DOS`, `IBM OS/2`, or `Microsoft Windows`. `CentOS` is a linux distribution, which would generally use `.sh` files as scripts, not `.bat` or `.cmd`. I have therefore modified your attached tags. Please take more care in future to make your question available to the appropriate audience, if you wish it to be answered.

Comment: For the batch statement, how many tables are you writing to, and how many statements are you trying to send at once?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642303/cassandra-bulk-write-performance-with-java-driver-is-atrocious-compared-to-mongo/39642809#39642809https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642303/cassandra-bulk-write-performance-with-java-driver-is-atrocious-compared-to-mongo/39642809#39642809