# Cassandra bach query consistency

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am using **Cassandra Java driver**.

I have a use case in which I do batch insert data into various Cassandra tables having different partition key.

```
    BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
    batch.add (query1, query2, .....)
    session.executeAsync(batch);
```

Consider I have 20 queries in my batch statement, 15 queries are executed well and 5 queries failed.

**How can I know which queries failed and which got executed.**

I am using `executeAsync` because of performance perspective.

<**Edit1:**>

We are using 'unlogged batch query'.

Comment: Always try to keep batch size small. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699841/what-is-the-batch-limit-in-cassandra

Answer (score 2):

Logged multi partition batches are atomic, but at cost of performance.
From official Cassandra documentation:

> Batches are atomic by default. In the context of a Cassandra batch
>   operation, atomic means that if any of the batch succeeds, all of it
>   will.

So any query will succeed or no one.

Unlogged multi partition batches are not atomic. Better run each query async and then collect results individually, or collect them by same partition key and run them in logged batch.

For example:

```
    List<String> queries = new ArrayList<>();

    List<ResultSetFuture> results = queries.stream()
            .map(query -> session.executeAsync(query))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    results.stream()
            .map(result -> {
                try {
                    return Optional.ofNullable(result.getUninterruptibly());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // do smth
                    return Optional.empty();
                }
            })
            .forEach(//do Something);
```

Also turn on java client connection pooling, so there is no new connection establishment on each query http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/pooling/

Comment: I think Batches are atomic if they are of 'one partition' key

Comment: But in my use case Bach query contain queries belonging to different partision

Comment: So, this is a common misuse of batch statement  - look  https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e#.x8t4t329p

Comment: Logged Batches are atomic among multiple partition keys but this is expensive.

Comment: We are using `Unlogged batch`

Comment: Ok, so they are not atomic - why don't run each query asynchronously and then collect result of each individually. In unlogged multi partitions batch there will be no performance, - look here https://inoio.de/blog/2016/01/13/cassandra-to-batch-or-not-to-batch/

Comment: Many thanks, but I have 150k queries / second, won't  firing these much queries per second create too much connections..?

Comment: At first you can group some statements by primary key and use logged batch, secondly turn on java client connection pooling, so there is no new connection establishment on each query http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/pooling/

Comment: could you please provide an example how I can track the status of each aysnc query